Can you compute in PTIME a weighted version of deficiency on a bipartite graph?
This question is about whether the measure on bipartite graphs called deficiency, which is PTIME to compute, can be generalized to a weighted variant and is still PTIME to compute in this setting.
Given a bipartite graph $G = (U \cup V, E)$ with $E \subseteq U \times V$, for any subset $U' \subseteq U$ of left-hand-side vertices, the deficiency of $U'$ is the number of left-hand-side vertices in $U'$ minus the number of right-hand-side vertices adjacent to $U'$. Formally, the deficiency is $\mathrm{def}_G(U') := |U'| - |\mathrm{N}(U')|$, where I write $\mathrm{N}(U')$ to mean the set of neighbors of vertices of $U'$, i.e., $\mathrm{N}(U') := \bigcup_{u \in U'} \{v \in V \mid (u, v) \in E\}$. The deficiency of $G$ (relative to $U$) is then the minimum deficiency of a subset of $U$, i.e., it is $\mathrm{def}(G) := \max_{U' \subseteq U} \mathrm{def}_G(U')$.
It is known that the deficiency of a bipartite graph $G$ can be computed in PTIME, e.g., from the theorem cited on the Wikipedia page which relates deficiency to the size of a maximum matching.
My question is: what happens in the weighted case? Suppose I have functions $f\colon U \to \mathbb{N}$ and $g\colon V \to \mathbb{N}$, and I now define the weighted deficiency of a set of left-hand-side vertices $U'$ to be the total weight of the vertices in $U'$ minus the total weight of the neighboring right-hand-side vertices. In other words, for $U' \subseteq U$, writing $f(U') := \sum_{u \in U'} f(u)$ and $g(V') := \sum_{v \in V'} g(v)$ for $V'\subseteq V$, I define $\mathrm{wdef}_{G,f,g}(U') := f(U') - g(\mathrm{N}(U'))$. And the weighted deficiency of the weighted graph is then $\mathrm{wdef}(G,f,g) := \max_{U' \subseteq U} \mathrm{wdef}_{G,f,g}(U')$.
Given a graph $G$ and weight functions $f$ and $g$, can I compute the weighted deficiency in PTIME?
(Note that, if the values of $f$ and $g$ are polynomial, then they can be encoded simply by duplicating the vertices. The interesting case is when the values of $f$ and $g$ are written in binary in the input.)

It turns out that this problem is just the project selection problem in disguise. In the project selection problem, you have a set of projects (left-hand-side vertices) yielding a revenue (their image by $f$), you have a set of machines (right-hand-side vertices) having a cost (their image by $g$), and whenever you select a project then you must purchase a specific subset of machines (its neighborhood in $G$). An optimal solution to the project selection problem maximizes the total revenue of selected project minus the total cost of the machines that must be purchased, which is precisely the definition of weighted deficiency above.
Then, the project selection problem can be solved in PTIME by reducing to a maximum flow problem.
Note that this result generalizes, beyond bipartite graphs, to arbitrary directed graphs. In the general problem, you have a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ and a cost function $f\colon V \to \mathbb{Z}$ giving an integer cost to every vertex, and you want to select a subset of vertices $V' \subseteq V$ such that $f(V') := \sum_{v \in V'} f(v)$ is maximal and, whenever there is a directed path from $u \in V$ to $v \in V$, then if $u \in V'$ then $v \in V'$. This problem also reduces to a variant of project selection on an arbitrary directed graph which can also be reduced to a maximum flow problem: cf these course notes.
